# insert query to add value in database

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, special-characters, mysql-real-escape-string

My database table structure is

```
mysql> desc webhotel.`first`;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| one   | varchar(45) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.19 sec)
```

I want to add ('Harshal') as field value for one

```
mysql> select * from webhotel.`first`;
+-------------+
| one         |
+-------------+
| ('Harshal') |
+-------------+    
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want this output

My problem is that i don't know how to insert a string containing single quotes into the database. I can use the IDE to do it, but i want an insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
INSERT INTO first (one) VALUES ('(''Harshal'')');
                                  ^^       ^^
```

Outcome:

```
|         ONE |
|-------------|
| ('Harshal') |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d056c/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

If the value contains single quotes, you can use double quotes in MySQL to enter the string:

```
INSERT INTO first (one)
VALUES ("('Harshal')");
```

or you can escape the quotes:

```
INSERT INTO first (one)
VALUES ('(\'Harshal\')');
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on the server side software you are using, you should look into 'prepared statements'. here's the link for [PHP](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), which provides easy to follow code.  while the other answers technically work, prepared statements were created to specifically address this problem, and will help alleviate some of the issues the other answers will give you.

Answer (score -3):

Below are the two ways you can use insert query.

```
INSERT into tablename values ('colValue1', 'colValue2')

INSERT into tablename (`colname1`, `colname2`) values ('colValue1', 'colValue2')
```

Visit http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp for more sql tutorials

Comment: How does this answer his question about inserting values that contain special characters?

Comment: And another -1 for recommending w3fools.